# AngularJS expression doesn't update when set to a value returned by the server using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I have an angularjs file which connects to a server using signalR. This is my code:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctr">

        //THE BELOW BUTTON SHOULD CHANGE THE VALUE OF {{testo}}
        <button ng-click="AggiornaTesto()">Cliccami</button>

        <input type="text" ng-model="input" />

        //THe EXPRESSION BELOW ONLY UPDATES IF I PRESS THE BUTTON "CLICCAMI" TWICE
        {{testo}}

        <br />
        Stato Connessione: {{statoconnessione}}
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
        app.controller("myctr", function ($scope) {
            $scope.testo = "";
            $scope.input = "";
            $scope.btnenabled = "true";
            $scope.statoconnessione = "";
            $.connection.myHub1.client.JSMet1 = function (x) {

                //THE FOLLOWING LINE IS EXECUTED CORRECTLY 
                //BECAUSE IN THE CONSOLE I CAN SEE IT IN THE CONSOLE, 
                //AND THE VALUE OF X IS CORRECT
                console.log("JSMet1 " + Math.random()+" "+x);

                //MAYBE ALSO THE FOLLOWING LINE IS EXECUTED BUT THE 
                //EXPRESSION {{testo}} IS UPDATED ONLY IF I PRESS THE BUTTON TWICE
                $scope.testo = x;
            };
            $scope.AggiornaTesto = function () {
                console.log("AggiornaTesto " + Math.random());
                $.connection.myHub1.server.cSMet1($scope.input);
            };
        });
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $.connection.hub.stateChanged = function (stato) { $scope.statoconnessione = stato };
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is that the expression {{testo}} is updated one time yes and one time no. meanwhile it should be updated every time i press the "cliccami" button. The function linked to the button, namely:

```
$.connection.myHub1.client.JSMet1 = function (x) {....}
```

is executed every time I press the button because I have checked the console and the console.log function is executed. But the next line, that is

```
$scope.testo = x;
```

doesn't seem to be executed becuse the {{testo}} doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called a digest cycle in angularJS that does the two way data-binding for you automatically on all the known angular's directives. In your case, you got to trigger the digest cycle yourself, so that `{{testo}}` will be changed to the new value. For that you got to call `$scope.$apply()`
More info about digest cycle here http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: @NicolaSecco glad I could help !

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when you mix angular code with libraries that are not aware of angular. When you pass a callback function to something outside angular you have to manually trigger an angular digest loop.

The cleanest way is to ensure that all callback code happens inside a call to `$scope.$apply()`:

```
$.connection.myHub1.client.JSMet1 = function (x) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log("JSMet1 " + Math.random()+" "+x);
        $scope.testo = x;
    })
});
```